# Extended chords: What is the difference between dominant, major, minor, major-minor chords?

Tags: chords

Extended chords (7th or higher) have 4 basic modes: dominant, major, minor, major+minor. What is the difference between  them?

Comment: Extended chords are chords built above the 7th. So C7 isn't considered extended, but C9 is.

Comment: But I am also asking support  for vBul sseventh chords as well. I cant say if seventh chords can also be cosidered extended.

Comment: What do you mean by "vBul"? And Dom answered your question, that seventh chords aren't considered extensions. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_chord: "In music, extended chords are tertian chords (built from thirds) or triads with notes extended, or added, beyond the seventh." Not a definitive source by far, but should represent the consensus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mode I assume you mean chord quality. Typically we only have chord qualities for the seventh chords. Extended chords are indicated with ♯ and ♭ preceding the reflective numbers, such as C♯11 indicating that the 11th note is sharpened from the usual major scale. The quality of the chord therefore refers to everything below the extensions.

A dominant chord is made of a major triad plus a minor 7th, i.e. 1-3-5-♭7. The name originates from the fact that the V7 chord (i.e. the chord built on the fifth note of the major scale. This scale degree is also known as the dominant) typically has a minor 7, i.e. GBDF in C major.
A major chord is a major triad. A major 7th chord indicates an added major 7th, i.e. 1-3-5-7.
A minor chord is a minor triad. A minor 7th chord indicates an added minor 7th, i.e. 1-♭3-5-♭7.
By major-minor chord, I think you mean minor-major 7th chord, which is built from a minor triad plus an added major 7th, i.e. 1-♭3-5-7.
There are also other possibilities. So far you've listed every combination of major/minor triads with major/minor sevenths, but you can also include diminished and augmented triads and also include the fully diminished seventh chord, which includes a diminished seventh, i.e. 1-♭3-♭5-7.

So you can distinguish chords by both quality, which indicates the quality of the triad and the quality of the seventh, and then by the extensions, which are indicated by numbers along with flats/sharps.

Comment: Sevenths : 'Major/minor' (chord) is known to some as an alternative name for dominant - containing M3 and m7. As opposed to 'minor/major, which has m3 and M7.